# qt creator create getter and setter with "get"

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm using qt creator to create getter and setter automatically and i choose prefer getter name without "get". I find it's not working. I still got getter with "get";
like this

```
class A
{
int getTest() const;
void setTest(const int& test);
public:
int _test;
}
```

is "_test" wrong?

Comment: did you take a look at [this post](https://forum.qt.io/topic/64352/how-to-customize-settings-for-creating-getter-and-setter-methods)? How did you choose "prefer getter name without get"?

Comment: @Salvo i check this page, is that means i should use  test_?  i find using "_test" style works fine in some of my cpp; i choose "prefer getter name without get" in qt creator ->tools->options->c++->code style->edit code style->getter and setter->prefer getter name without "get"

Comment: I tried in this moment what you said and I managed to create the get method **int test() const;** without get for a variable _test. Are you sure you have the "prefer getter name without get" option ***checked***?

Comment: @Salvo thx for concern. yeah im sure. This makes me feel confuse. In some class it's ok some are not;